# Generate an email button to log a user into a web page without API

Tags: html, email, authentication, automation

TLDR: Is it possible to email a login button which will open a web page and enter the appropriate user information into the username/password fields? Is it possible to embed this within an HTML button, or possibly in SQL injection? If so, where should I start my research to make this happen?

OK, so what I am tasked with is generating the billing lists for about 2000 non-technical users. Currently we use a third party billing site which does not have an API or any way to authenticate users from the URL heading. What we have been doing is using mail-merge to email users their username and password along with a link to the billing site. This is great, except that our users are... *special*. We get dozens of phone calls a day from elderly users who can't copy/paste the given information into the website.

What I am looking for is someone to point me in the right direction for making an email *click here* button that will open the web page, enter the username and password (from a CSV/XML of usernames/passwords) and click enter. 
I'd even settle for opening the webpage with their credentials filled into the appropriate fields. Is there a way to do this? What is the best way to go about this?

Before we get into best practices/security, CC information isn't stored on the site, and the only user info view-able is the invoice, so security isn't a huge concern here since the users can't set their own passwords (username / password generated from static fields in another database silo). 
Not looking for someone to do this project for me, but perhaps a few friendly pointers in the right direction for how to do this.

Comment: clarify your question more precisely.

Comment: Is it possible to email a login button which will open a web page and enter the appropriate user information into the username/password fields? Is it possible to embed this within an HTML button, or possibly in SQL injection?

Comment: you want to send HML in your email

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to email a login button which will open a web page and enter the appropriate user information into the username/password fields?

Not unless either:

- The website is specifically designed to allow that. Since you said it was a third party side, then you would have to ask the people who wrote it.
- The site suffered from an XSS security vulerability. (Explaining how to search for one would be too broad for a SO answer, searching for one would be illegal pretty much everywhere).